# In Spark Scala, how to create a column with substring() using locate() as a parameter?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a dataset that is like the following:

```
val df = Seq("samb id 12", "car id 13", "lxu id 88").toDF("list")
```

[image]

I want to create a column that will be a string containing only the values after Id. The result would be something like:

```
val df_result = Seq(("samb id 12",12), ("car id 13",13), ("lxu id 88",88)).toDF("list", "id_value")
```

[image]

For that, I am trying to use `substring`. For the the parameter of the starting position to extract the substring, I am trying to use locate. But it gives me an error saying that it should be an Int and not a column type.

What I am trying is like:

```
df
.withColumn("id_value", substring($"list", locate("id", $"list") + 2, 2))
```

The error I get is:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 required: Int
.withColumn("id_value", substring($"list", locate("id", $"list") + 2, 2))
                                                                 ^
```

How can I fix this and continue using locate() as a parameter?

**UPDATE**
Updating to give an example in which @wBob answer doesn't work for my real world data: my data is indeed a bit more complicated than the examples above.

It is something like this:

```
val df = Seq(":option car, lorem :ipsum: :ison, ID R21234, llor ip", "lst ID X49329xas ipsum :ion: ip_s-")
```

[image]

The values are very long strings that don't have a specific pattern.

Somewhere in the string that is always a part written `ID XXXXX`. The XXXXX varies, but it is always the same size (5 characters) and always after a `ID` .

I am not being able to use neither `split` nor `regexp_extract` to get something in this pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear if you want *the third item* or *the first number* from the list, but here are a couple of examples which should help:

```
// Assign sample data to dataframe
val df = Seq("samb id 12", "car id 13", "lxu id 88").toDF("list")

df
    .withColumn("t1", split($"list", "\\ ")(2))
    .withColumn("t2", regexp_extract($"list", "\\d+", 0))
    .withColumn("t3", regexp_extract($"list", "(id )(\\d+)", 2))
    .withColumn("t4", regexp_extract($"list", "ID [A-Z](\\d{5})", 1))
    .show()
```

You can use functions like `split` and `regexp_extract` with `withColumn` to create new columns based on existing values.  `split` splits out the list into an array based on the delimiter you pass in.  I have used space here, escaped with two slashes to split the array.  The array is zero-based hence specifying `2` gets the third item in the array.  `regexp_extract` uses regular expressions to extract from strings.  here I've used `\\d` which represents digits and `+` which matches the digit 1 or many times.  The third column, `t3`, again uses `regexp_extract` with a similar RegEx expression, but using brackets to group up sections and `2` to get the second group from the regex, ie the `(\\d+)`.  NB I'm using additional slashes in the regex to escape the slashes used in the `\d`.

My results:

[image]

If your real data is more complicated please post a few simple examples where this code does not work and explain why.

Comment: Hi, @wBob, thanks a lot for helping! My real data is indeed a bit more complicated than what I had showed. I updated my question to include an example that is closer to my real data. Since the update, I have been trying to change the parameters in regex_extract to make it work, but I haven't been successful yet. If I am able to do it, I will come back here to share my final result. Again, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Can you confirm what your expected results are for your new data please?  eg is it just 21234, 49329 ?

Comment: I've added a t4 example which works with your new data - please check.  Also feel free to upvote or mark as answer if you think this has been useful!